# Python regex not matching row if the target is at the end of the line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a key-value pairing chunk by chunk instead of substrings, so say I'm trying to match `from=email@email.com` I'm using `from=email@email.com(?!|\S)` to make sure I don't hit on substring matches. And according to https://regex101.com/r/ehuXFY/1 it works. But here's my unit tests and the case where the match is at the end of the string doesn't seem to work:

```
import unittest
import re


class MyRegexFuTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        lines = [
            'from=test_email@email.com\talias= <test_email@email.com>\trcptlist=test_recipient@email.com\trip=8.8.8.8\tdate=1486528190\tsubject= Test Subject\treply_to=test_email@email.com\treport=leoisafatcat\tattach_3=New List.xls']
        whitelisted_pairs = ['attach_3=New List.xls']
        lines = filter(lambda line: any(
            map(lambda pair: not re.match(r'%s(?!\S)' % pair, line),
                whitelisted_pairs)), lines)
        self.assertEqual(len(lines), 0)

    def test_another_case(self):
        lines = [
            'from=test_email@email.com\talias= <test_email@email.com>\trcptlist=test_recipient@email.com\trip=8.8.8.8\tdate=1486528190\tsubject= Test Subject\treply_to=test_email@email.com\treport=leoisafatcat\tattach_3=New List.xls']
        whitelisted_pairs = ['from=test_email@email.com']
        lines = filter(lambda line: any(
            map(lambda pair: not re.match(r'%s(?!\S)' % pair, line),
                whitelisted_pairs)), lines)
        self.assertEqual(len(lines), 0)

    def test_no_match(self):
        lines = [
            'from=test_email@email.com\talias= <test_email@email.com>\trcptlist=test_recipient@email.com\trip=8.8.8.8\tdate=1486528190\tsubject= Test Subject\treply_to=test_email@email.com\treport=leoisafatcat\tattach_3=New List.xls']
        whitelisted_pairs = ['from=test_email@email.co']
        lines = filter(lambda line: any(
            map(lambda pair: not re.match(r'%s(?!\S)' % pair, line),
                whitelisted_pairs)), lines)
        self.assertEqual(len(lines), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()



..F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_something (__main__.MyRegexFuTestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stupidfatcat/PycharmProjects/adhoc/so_help.py", line 13, in test_something
    self.assertEqual(len(lines), 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: can you explain the differences? why `from=test_email@email.co` and not `.com` ?

Comment: @jean-francoisFabre I don't want to match on email.co because the line is email.com. I.e. I don't want substring matches.

Comment: why not using `\b` for word boundary instead of this complex `(?!\S)` crap?

Comment: @jean-francoisfabre ah not knowing regex very well is the reason. \b is much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) when you should be using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search).

`match` attempts to match the regex at the beginning of the line. Thus, only the two last test cases match because they start at the very beginning of the line.

`search` on the other hand, has the behavior you expected. It matches the regex against any portion of the line.

Comment: `re.match` does not attempt to match the regex "against the whole line". It only matches at the start of string. It is not Java where `.matches()` requires a full string match.

Comment: Oh, right. I'm learning something :-) Never done regex in Java though. I edited my answer.

Comment: `re.match` is not aware of *lines*, it will always look for a match at the start of the *whole string*. Even if there is a `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: I'm using the word `line` here because, in his code, each string against which the regex matches is a line.